# bad credential error in spring-boot application

Tags: sql-server, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, naming-conventions

I'm working on a spring-boot application that uses Oauth2 and connects SqlServer. So when I'm hitting the access token URL that looks like this:

`localhost:8081/oauth/token?client_secret=secret&client_id=web&grant_type=password&username=XXXX&password=XXXXXXX`

And the response which I'm getting is:

`{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Bad credentials"
}`

So I feel it is because of @Table annotation and the naming convention bug which hibernate have. I/m using `spring 1.5.9 and hibernate 5.0.12`.

My Account.java file is:

```
package com.oauth.oserver.entities;
import javax.persistence.*;


@Entity
@Table(name = "userinfo")
public class Account {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
@Column(name = "name")
private String username;
@Column(name = "password")
private String password;

public Account() {
}

public Account(String username, String password) {

    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;

}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
}
```

Database contains table whose name is `UserInfo`.

Comment: can you post your controller and service here?

Answer (score 0):

From OAuth2 doc(https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749), the error corresponds to :

> invalid_grant
> The provided authorization grant (e.g., authorization
> code, resource owner credentials) or refresh token is
> invalid, expired, revoked, does not match the redirection
> URI used in the authorization request, or was issued to
> another client.

So please make sure that you have entered the right grants. If so, change @table name to "UserInfo" instead of "userinfo". Hope that helps.
And please check this out for table naming strategies : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/cfg/ImprovedNamingStrategy.html

Comment: Previously it was 'UserInfo' only and after that it automatically generated a table in my database with name 'user_info' with following columns: name, password and id

Comment: Then either make "@Table name" = "user_info" or 
remove "@Table name" annotation and make sure the naming strategy is ImprovedNamingStrategy.

Comment: That too didnt work. I cant change the name of the table, so trying to change the property files and code only so that it correctly maps the database table.

Do you know any other solution.

Comment: Did you changed the '@Table name' to "UserInfo" , too?

Comment: NO, it didn't work. It gives folllowing response:

`{
    "error": "invalid_grant",
    "error_description": "Bad credentials"
}`

Comment: Are you sure that your OAuth credentials are correct?